# Web Application in IIS 8 not consume a web service.

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, iis-8

I make a web application in Visual Studio 2012 that consume an Axis Web Service. When run my application in debug mode (iis express) works fine and get data from web service, but when deploy my application in IIS 8 return "***Unable connect to the remote server***" (SocketException). I think it's an IIS configuration that I need . I took several hours trying to solve this problem and your help would be a blessing . Beforehand thank you very much.

Comment: probably proxy settings different.

Comment: can you get to the web service address in a browser from a) the server; and b) your dev pc?

Comment: @GuyLowe ... is correct.

Comment: so you are saying that your web application attempts to consume an outside web service and fails with the above error? And it works from a browser from the server?

Comment: @GuyLowe, work fine in debug mode when run in developer time.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov... you are right, tanks. The solution was set proxy addres in web.config.